# What does "applies in spades" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Could someone explain to me the meaning of this phrase in English language?

> This, of course, **applies in spades** to a complete Pattern Language

I especially refer to that ***applies in spades*** thing. Of course, I understand what each word means separately, but I do not understand what all that together means.

I found that sentence [here](http://www.aleax.it/Python/5ep.html).

Comment: See the definition of [in spades](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-spades) - it means it applies to a large amount

Comment: I feel shame because I used the same dictionary but did not think to search for that expression. Thank you very much

Comment: No shame, but congratulations! You have learned something important about dictionaries, which will serve you in future learning.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The phrase "in spades" comes from bridge, [where spades are the highest-ranking suit](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=spades). So the real sense of the phrase is that if something applies "in spades" it is manifestly superior to a rival, even if the rival might resemble it in many ways.